# MySQL - select product_id from 2 different tables and group results

Tags: mysql, group-by

**situation:**

table 1 - #__virtuemart_products

```
virtuemart_product_id | product_special
PRODUCTS_IDS | 0 or 1
```

table 2 - #__virtuemart_product_badges

```
virtuemart_product_id | product_badge
PRODUCTS_IDS | for this situation code 3
```

I have a default SQL

```
SELECT p.`virtuemart_product_id`
FROM `#__virtuemart_products` as p
WHERE p.`product_special` = 1;
```

results is product IDs like 2,3,225,...

I need modify this SQL syntax for select IDs from 2 different tables and return one column.

If I modify syntax like that:

```
SELECT p.`virtuemart_product_id`, badges_table.`virtuemart_product_id`
FROM `#__virtuemart_products` as p, `#__virtuemart_product_badges` as badges_table
WHERE p.`product_special` = 1 OR badges_table.`badge` = 3
```

Result is:

```
virtuemart_product_id | virtuemart_product_id
1 | 123
1 | 321
1 | 231
....
```

1. why is first column 1,1,1,...? here must be product_id, no product_special code
2. I need group this results into one column virtuemart_product_id

What I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is UNION of the IDs fetched from two different tables.

```
    SELECT p.`virtuemart_product_id`, badges_table.`virtuemart_product_id`
    FROM `#__virtuemart_products` as p, `#__virtuemart_product_badges` as 
    badges_table
    WHERE p.`product_special` = 1 OR badges_table.`badge` = 3
```

What the above query is doing is, it is performing a join between the two tables with the condition that product_special should be 1 or badge should be 3. Hence, each row from one table will be joined with each row of the other table where the condition will satisfy.

To get IDs from both the tables you can get the results from each table according to condition and then perform a UNION on them. So for example

```
     (SELECT `virtuemart_product_id` FROM `#__virtuemart_products` WHERE 
     `product_special` = 1) 
      UNION 
     (SELECT `virtuemart_product_id` FROM 
     `#__virtuemart_product_badges` WHERE `badge` = 3)
```

I hope this helps.